# CLI command to update simple XML file

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, xml

I would like to programmatically update a string in a very simple XML config file, such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x>
    <z>should be changed</z>
</x>
<y>
    <z>should NOT be changed</z>
</y>
```

Does a simple CLI command exist that will update x/z and NOT y/z ? Perhaps with an XPath selector argument, such as:

```
$ xml-update myfile.xml /x/z "my new string"
```

I could write something in Perl or Python, but given the simplicity of this problem, I guess there must be a clever Unix utility that does this already.

**Update**: I found this but it seems a bit overkill. And I would have to learn XSLT first. http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/12/05/xml-editing-bash-script/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [xml2/2xml](http://dan.egnor.name/xml2/) tools to process XML on the command line without too much fuss.  `xml2` converts an XML document into a line-oriented format suitable for use with traditional text processing tools like `awk` or `sed`, and `2xml` takes this format and converts it back to XML.

For your example, if I take this document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<x>
    <z>should be changed</z>
</x>
<y>
    <z>should NOT be changed</z>
</y>
</doc>
```

Running `xml2` on that content yields:

```
$ xml2 < doc.xml
/doc/x/z=should be changed
/doc/y/z=should NOT be changed
```

I can modify the content of the `<z>` element like this

```
xml2 < doc.xml |
sed '/\/doc\/x\/z/ s/should be changed/look ma no hands/' |
2xml | tidyp -xml -i -q
```

I'm using a `sed` search expression to look explicitly for the line
starting with `/doc/y/z`, and then modifying the content of that line,
which gives us:

```
<doc>
  <x>
    <z>look ma no hands</z>
  </x>
  <y>
    <z>should NOT be changed</z>
  </y>
</doc>
```

I passed the output through `tidyp`, an XML formatter, because
otherwise the document would look like:

```
<doc><x><z>look ma no hands</z></x><y><z>should NOT be changed</z></y></doc>
```

...which is syntactically correct but harder to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find an Ubuntu package for ```tidyp```, but this answer lists some Ubuntu-ready alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16090892/604515